# Autoupdating a windows application without using a separate program

Tags: windows, auto-update

I am looking for ways to enable silent auto updates for my windows application. The update process should be such that only the changed files are downloaded and replaced. So, I have planned to integrate it with my application. Considering the fact that renaming/moving a running executable (or its folder) is possible, Is it alright to use the application to update itself?. Is renaming/moving a running executable dangerous?. What are all the advantages of using a separate updater program over using the application itself to update it?

Thanks!.

Comment: Users often don't want 'silent auto updates' and they are generally not possible anyway because of permissions/privileges/UAC.  You need a new update plan.

Comment: The application is installed in Local application data (to support silent auto updates) which always has full access rights.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main disadvantage with allowing the application to update itself is that it makes it harder to be sure that all activity has stopped, for example that all asynchronous I/O has completed, all user interface elements closed, and all data flushed to disk.  Typically, with a separate updater, the application process will exit before the update begins so that you can be certain nothing is happening that will interfere with (or be interfered with by) the update process.

If you're just trying to avoid having a separate build, you could design the application so that after downloading the new content it makes a copy of itself (or, if the updater component has itself been updated, extracts a copy of the new version of itself) in a temporary location and launches this copy in update mode.  An application that decides at launch-time whether it is being an updater instance or a regular instance is easy to design and doesn't have the problem mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The windows operating system will not let you overwrite an application which is running.  You need another application to do that.  One process I have is that I have my downloader application download files but if they are in use they are given the extension .update.

My application then when it starts looks for any files with that extension in the folder and sub-folders.  If it finds one it will launch a patcher application and terminate itself.  The patcher waits for the program files to become free and then moved the .update files over the top of the application files and restarts the application.

It takes a split second extra to launch when there are updates but the user doesn't notice.

In addition:
The advantage of a separate updater program is about modularity and cleanliness.  You could reuse the updater software and its code is probably not core to what your application is doing.  Plus unless you make it multi-threaded its going to impact the interactivity of your application whilst it working.

I've seen a lot of programmers go for the monolithic approach to deployment (with static builds), however modularity still has major benefits if you ask me.

Comment: Modifying/Replacing/Deleting a running executable may not work, but renaming/moving it does work in xp, vista and windows 7.

Comment: In most cases applications cannot be updated while in use, so I don't think any potential impact on the interactivity of the application is likely to be an issue.